# Get all subitems from nested JSON in Javascript/jQuery recursivly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i got some nested JSON like the following:

```
[
{"ID": 1,
 "Name": "This is a Catogory, i don´t need them",
 "Items": [
          {"ID": 2,
           "Name": "Some String here",
           "Items": [{
               "ID": 2,
               "Name": "Some String here",
                ... etc ...
          },
          },
          {"ID": 5,
           "Name": "Some String here"
          },
          {"ID": 3,
           "Name": "Some String here"
          },
          {"ID": 4,
           "Name": "Some String here"
          }
          ]
},
...
]
```

Now i need to save all subitems with name and ID into a dictionary, with the ID as key.
This should be do with a recursivly method i think. Do not know exactly how, i only get all items or only the first items from the subitems :-/
For some simple code, a good link or something else I would be grateful.

Sorry, I think it was not really clear enough. The subitems can also has subitems!
I have no influence on nesting structure.

Comment: How is this recursive? Can the subitems have further subitems? If not, then this is a simple .each() call.

Comment: Any reason not to use native JSON.parse or Crockford's JSON2 lib?

Comment: i will test it. not seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a recursive function to pull out the data you want if the depth of the object is unknown.

```
var test = [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "This is a Catogory, i don´t need them",
        "Items": [
            {
                "ID": 2,
                "Name": "Some String here",
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "ID": 12,
                        "Name": "Some String here"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 13,
                        "Name": "Some String here"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": 5,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            },
            {
                "ID": 3,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            },
            {
                "ID": 4,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "This is a Catogory, i don´t need them",
        "Items": [
            {
                "ID": 7,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            },
            {
                "ID": 8,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            },
            {
                "ID": 9,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            },
            {
                "ID": 10,
                "Name": "Some String here"
            }
        ]
    }
]

var kvp = [];
function parseItems(startArray)
{
    console.log(startArray);
    if(startArray === undefined)
        return;
    for (var i = 0, l = startArray.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(startArray[i].Items === undefined)
                continue;
        for (var j = 0, k = startArray[i].Items.length; j < k; j++) {
            kvp[startArray[i].Items[j].ID] = startArray[i].Items[j].Name;
            parseItems(startArray[i].Items);
        }
    }
}

console.log(kvp);
```

This will print out something like this:

```
[
    2: "Some String here",
    3: "Some String here",
    4: "Some String here",
    5: "Some String here",
    7: "Some String here",
    8: "Some String here",
    9: "Some String here",
    10: "Some String here",
    12: "Some String here",
    13: "Some String here"
]
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/YfhNt/2/) is a jsfiddle example

Comment: okay, thanks at first for this! works great as far. but what about when the items has subitems. I have no influence on nesting structure. I ma sorry, the json example was perhaps not entirely clear.

Comment: Updated the code to get generate the key value pair recursively.